# Fix code indentation and prevent git/svn blame information

Tags: git, svn

Is there any possibility to fix code indentation and keep original authors of the code in svn or git?

Comment: Aside from languages where indentation matters (like Python), what value is added to the project by "fixing code indentation" if no other changes are being made to those blocks of code?

Comment: It matters if one by mistake used different indentation style than code convention in the project.

Answer (score 2):

For Git, you can do:

```
git blame -w <file>
```

From `man git blame`:

> -w
>
> Ignore whitespace when comparing the parent's version and the child's to find where the lines came from.

As mentioned in [@alroc's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/39496618/2747593) (since deleted), the changes will still be tracked in the commits that change formatting, but this will allow you to see the original author when needed.

Answer (score 1):

With Subversion you should use `svn blame --extensions --ignore-all-space PATH`

or just `svn blame -x -w PATH`.

Read [SVNBook | `svn blame` command line reference](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.extensions).

There are several extensions in addition to `--ignore-all-space`:

```
--ignore-space-change (-b)
--ignore-eol-style
--show-c-function (-p)
--unified (-u)
```

Read about [`--extensions` in SVNBook](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.extensions).